# Styles and javascript not working after refresh jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am facing this issue when using jQuery Mobile. When I land to the home page all the CSS and javascript works fine. When clicked on the links or buttons the events works as expected.

But after going to any page say About Us and then refresh that particular page, if we come back to home page some of the CSS are missing and also the javascript is not working anymore, though the links works fine.

simple alert also wont work after coming back to the home page.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You have a lot of inline styles on your body, is there a reason you haven't used a seperate CSS script?

Comment: @agryson the reason is for my index page body i have applied a different style and other pages bode tag different style.

Comment: Use a class or id then to make sure it only applies to the correct page, something lke `class="main-page"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard Ajax navigation in jQuery Mobile will only retrieve the `<body>` of the page you are navigating to. This means that any CSS or scripts linked to/defined in the header of a subsequent page will simply be ignored.
This means that the header of the first page the user load must contain all the styles/scripts required on all subsequent pages.
If you refresh "about", this becomes your initial page, and apparently this page's header does not contain the same content as your homepage.
You can either update your headers or use `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"` attributes in your links to disable JQM ajax navigation and navigate to/from the "about" page in a more regular fashion, where the whole page will be loaded.
You can check [this page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html) for more details.

Comment: Now I am able to get the css as i have put the stylesheet used in index page, in the page that i refreshed also. But the same way I have put the javascript needed for index page in both the pages(index and the page being refreshed) but the javascript isn't working. Any idea on this?

Comment: I gave data-ajax="false" in other pages. Now its working but the transition effect does not happen as mentioned. Thanks :)

Comment: additionaly, document ready will not work as when navigating from page to page in ajax. You will need to bind to [pageinit](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

Answer (score 0):

Going to the other page and refreshing is removing all of your inline styles in the `<body>`.

Try using an external style sheet to ensure that the styling is conserved.

Your `<body>` before refresh:

```
<body style="background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E7E7E7, #121212); background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#E7E7E7), to(#121212));" class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-d">
```

And your `<body>` after the refresh:

```
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c">
```

This in-page script is also disappearing, try to move it to an external script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".second-tech").hide();
                $(".third-tech").hide();

                $("#mobileicon").click(function(){
                    if ($(".second-tech").is(':visible')) {

                       //... Lots more code...

                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: no its not working i tried putting it into different files still the same bug.

Comment: the link is updated you can view the page source for the code.. I wud have pasted some code but i dont know where the problem is

Comment: I just tested the link and it's working fine now... Scenario tested: _Click about_ **->** _refresh_ **->** _click home_, is it he javascript that's still not working or something else?